# mysql uses "on update" and sets a default albeit I never told it to do so

Tags: mysql, sql

I executed the following query on my mysql server:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  count integer NOT NULL,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

When I looked into phpmyadmin I was suprised.
The `created_at` column had a default set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` was also there.

How can this even happen?
It shouldnt do that, right?

Answer (score 0):

Although this behavior is surprising to me, it is actually explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> For any TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column in a table, you can assign the
>   current timestamp as the default value, the auto-update value, or
>   both:
>
> - An auto-initialized column is set to the current timestamp for inserted rows that specify no value for the column.
> - An auto-updated column is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed
>     from its current value. An auto-updated column remains unchanged if
>     all other columns are set to their current values. To prevent an
>     auto-updated column from updating when other columns change,
>     explicitly set it to its current value. To update an auto-updated
>     column even when other columns do not change, explicitly set it to the
>     value it should have (for example, set it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Comment: So the follow up question is: Why this only happens to `created_at` and not to `updated_at`? And when is a coloumn recognized as `auto-initialized` and `auto-updated`? Thank you so far already :)

Comment: looks like the **first** TIMESTAMP  is set that way automatically. "It need not be the first TIMESTAMP column in a table that is automatically initialized or updated to the current timestamp. However, to specify automatic initialization or updating for a different TIMESTAMP column, you must suppress the automatic properties for the first one." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html